Room DB Init if not exists by 2 combined colums
I have a Room Table with some colums.

Now I want to add another column. But it should only be added if the combination of Year and Week does not exists. Otherwise it should be Ignored.
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun initInsertWeek(week: Week)

How to archive that by an query?
This is "Week"
@Entity(tableName = "Weeks")

data class Week(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Long? = null,

val year: Int,
val week: Int,
val workingTime: Int,

@ColumnInfo(name = "timeStamp", defaultValue = "0")
val timeStamp: Long = 0,

@ColumnInfo(name = "weeklyWorkingDayCount", defaultValue = "5")
val weeklyWorkingDayCount: Int = 5,

@ColumnInfo(name = "weekDailyDurations", defaultValue = "462:462:462:462:462:0:0")
val weekDailyDurations: String = "462:462:462:462:462:0:0"

)
I hope you can help me.

You can define a

UNIQUE index on the two columns, and
use INSERT OR IGNORE (which you have anyway by using @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE))

As the index needs to consist of multiple columns (i.e. it is a composite index) then you need to use the indicies parameter of the @Entity annotation.
For a composite index on the year and week column you can use:-
@Entity(tableName = "Weeks",
    indices = [Index("year","week", unique = true)]
)

You then do not need, the initInsertWeek function. You also may not need the getWeek function.

you should use unique constraints to entity like below,
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Index
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(
    tableName = "weeks",
    indices = [Index(value = ["year", "week"], unique = true)]
)
data class Week(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long? = null,

    val year: Int,
    val week: Int,
    val workingTime: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "timeStamp", defaultValue = "0")
    val timeStamp: Long = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "weeklyWorkingDayCount", defaultValue = "5")
    val weeklyWorkingDayCount: Int = 5,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "weekDailyDurations", defaultValue = "462:462:462:462:462:0:0")
    val weekDailyDurations: String = "462:462:462:462:462:0:0"
)


Implement the initInsertWeek method that checks for an existing entry before inserting:
@Dao
interface WeekDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE) // Ignore if the entry exists
    suspend fun insert(week: Week)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM weeks WHERE year = :year AND week = :week")
    suspend fun getWeek(year: Int, week: Int): Week?

    @Transaction
    suspend fun initInsertWeek(week: Week) {
        // Check if the week already exists
        val existingWeek = getWeek(week.year, week.week)
        if (existingWeek == null) {
            // If it doesn't exist, insert it
            insert(week)
        }
    }
}

Now call,
 weekDao.initInsertWeek(week)
 weekDao.initInsert(week) //Try this also

